Copy cells from one column to another column with criteria through big size of data
I have this code that copying values from column BP to Column BE.
The code copied all values expect those cells that contain "#N/A" and is empty.
This code goes through thousands of data. But, suddenly it take so long for running the code and keep on running for more than half an hour.
Could anyone help me to fix this code? Thank you in advance :)
Sub copy()
Dim sortir As Range, g As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL")
        Set sortir = .Range("BP2:BP" & .Range("BP" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each g In sortir
            If Not (g.Text = "#N/A" Or IsEmpty(g.Value)) Then
                .Cells(g.Row, "BE").Value = .Cells(g.Row, "BP")
            End If
        Next g
     End With
End Sub


Please, try the next code. It uses arrays, all processing is done in memory and processed array content is dropped at once, at the end of the code. So it should be very fast, even for large ranges:
Sub copyCells()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrBP, arrBE, i As Long
 Const srcCol As String = "BP" 'you can change if needing to insert/delete other columns
 Const retCol As String = "BE" 'it can be also changed in the future, if needed
 
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL") 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, srcCol).End(xlUp).row
 
 arrBP = ws.Range(ws.cells(2, srcCol), ws.cells(lastR, srcCol)).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 arrBE = ws.Range(ws.cells(2, retCol), ws.cells(lastR, retCol)).Value 'place existing range in an array
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrBP)
    If Not IsError(arrBP(i, 1)) Then
        If arrBP(i, 1) <> "" Then
            arrBE(i, 1) = arrBP(i, 1) 'place in the return array the value
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 
 'drop the processed array content, at once:
 ws.cells(2, retCol).Resize(UBound(arrBE)).Value = arrBE
 
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Plese, send some feedback after testing it.

First thing: "Copy" is a Method attached to various Objects in VBA; that makes it a bad choice of Subroutine name.
Next, if you know that things are going to take a while, then you should consider:

Temporarily turning off Calculation
Temporarily turning off Screen Updating
Giving yourself an indication of Progress
Periodically calling DoEvents, to check in the OS and not look like you've crashed
Alerting yourself when it completes

Sub CopyNonErrors()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sortir As Range, g As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL")
    
    Dim dsb As Boolean, sb As Variant, calc As XlCalculation, su As Boolean
    su = Application.ScreenUpdating: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    calc = Application.Calculation: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    dsb = Application.DisplayStatusBar: Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    'N.B. This is to prevent VBA from changing the boolean False value inte a "FALSE" string value:
    sb = IIf(TypeName(Application.StatusBar) = "Boolean", False, Application.StatusBar)
    
    Dim lCurr As Long, lTotal As Long
    
    'Define 2 corners of a rectangle
    Set sortir = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "BP"), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "BP").End(xlUp))
    lTotal = sortir.Cells.Count
    lCurr = 0
    
    If sortir.Cells(1,1).Row > 1 Then 'Make sure there is ANY data!
        For Each g In sortir.Cells
            lCurr = lCurr + 1
            Application.StatusBar = CStr(lCurr) & " of " & lTotal & " : " & Format(100 * lCurr / lTotal, "#0.00") & "%"
            If (lCurr Mod 50) = 0 Then DoEvents
        
            'Checking the Error Value directly, rather than for "#N/A" text
            If Not (g.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Or IsEmpty(g.Value)) Then
                g.EntireRow.Cells(, "BE").Value = g.Value
            End If
        Next g
    End If
    
    'Reset stuff
    Application.StatusBar = sb
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = dsb
    Application.Calculation = calc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = su
    
    Beep
    MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation
End Sub

